# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR while connecting private blockchain

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, connections

I'm working with private blockchain, and facing some issue with SSL configuration.

The system has two components:

1. The private blockchain that is configured on the VM.
2. The web application that initiating transactions.

There is the truffle config file of web app:

```
development: {
 host: "<serverIPAddress>",
 port: 8545,            
 network_id: "*",       
},
```

Provider configuration:

```
var web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new web3();

var provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        "http://" + truffleConfig.networks.development.host +
        ":" + truffleConfig.networks.development.port
    );
    
web3.setProvider(provider);
```

**Issue:**

Web application runs with HTTPS, and hence it gives an error when connection to the blockchain.

```
this request has been blocked the content must be served over https
```

If I use `"https://" + truffleConfig.networks.development.host +`, the error is

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Is there any way we can fix this issue?

It is working if we run web app with http, but we need to run web app with ssl only.

Comment: How about using `"https://"`?

Comment: @goodvibration, question updated